# zugrunde liegend / zugrunde zu legend

Tags: translation

These two are doing my head in. I need to understand for once and all what is underlying what in each case.

> Folglich entspricht der nach dem Marktordnungsrecht zugrunde zu legende Einfuhrpreis für Obst und Gemüse dem nach dem Zollrecht ermittelten Zollwert.
>
> Die der Arbeit zugrunde liegende Idee wurde von Berger entwickelt.

Is the Einfuhrpreis the basis of the Marktordnungsrecht, or vice versa?
Is the Arbeit the basis of the Idee or vice versa?

Bilingual dictionaries like Collins and Oxford most helpfully say "something underlying something" and "something is the basis of something". Thanks guys, really clear.

Comment: can you provide the full sentences?

Comment: Sentence 1: The "Einfuhrpreis" is the basis. You are required to use it as a basis.
Sentence 2: The "Idee" is the basis on which the "Arbeit" has to rest.

Comment: Full sentences provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *Zugrunde legen, liegen*

*Zugrunde legen* signifies a ternary relation. A person or entity (1), expressed by the subject, posits something (2), expressed by the accusative object, as the basis for something else (3), expressed by the dative object.

> **Welchen Begriff von Sicherheit** (2) wollen **wir** (1) **unseren Überlegungen** (3) zugrunde legen?
>
> "Which concept of security do we want to use as the basis for our reflections?"

Note that the dative object is often left out.

> Die beiden Analysen sind jedoch nicht direkt zu vergleichen, weil **sie** (1) **unterschiedliche Annahmen** (2) zugrunde legen.

*Zugrunde legen* frequently occurs in the passive, removing the agent (1). Additionally, prepositional phrases introduced by *bei* seem to be able to fill the (3) role.

> **Bei der Prüfung des Grundrentenanspruchs** (3) wird **der Steuerbescheid von 2019** (2) zugrunde gelegt werden.

*Zugrunde liegen* is similar, except that (1) is gone and (2) is expressed by the subject.

> **Welcher Begriff von Sicherheit** (2) liegt **diesen Überlegungen** (3) zugrunde?

Or, in your second example:

> die **der Arbeit** (3) zugrunde liegende **Idee** (2)
> = die Idee, **die** (2) **der Arbeit** (3) zugrunde liegt
> "the idea that serves as the basis of the work"

With the dative left out:

> **Welches Menschenbild** (2) liegt zugrunde?

(The alternation between *legen* and *liegen* should be familiar: *Er legt das Buch auf den Tisch*, *das Buch liegt auf dem Tisch*.)

## The gerundive

The last stumbling block is the [gerundive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerundive). It is formed by *zu* plus present participle and is a modal passive, similar to *sein* plus *zu* plus infinitive.

> das zu beseitigende Problem
> = das Problem, das zu beseitigen ist
> "the problem (that is) to be eliminated" *or* "the problem that must be eliminated"
>
> der nach dem Marktordnungsrecht zugrunde zu legende **Einfuhrpreis** (2)
> = der Preis, **der** (2) nach dem Marktordnungsrecht zugrunde zu legen ist
> "the price that (2), according to law, is to be used as a basis"

Answer (score 1):

> zu Grunde zu legende

This means, that no usable basis already exists, therefore the customs office has (in the sense of *is obliged to*) to provide the basis for the *Einfuhrpreis (import value)* according to the *Marktordnungsrecht*.

> zu Grunde liegend

The basis already exists, in the case of a paper simply by stating its reference.

So *zugrunde zu liegend* from the question title is wrong, since it combines the *zu* (indicating that something yet has **to** happen) with *liegend* (which says its already in place using grammatical construction of present participle).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a few additions to guidot's answer:

the surface this is easier than you think:

Note the different spelling of "liegen" and "legen". 
In English you "lay" something down and then it "lies" there. 
In German: Du "legst" etwas hin und dann "liegt" es da.

But when you go deeper, it's more complicated:

Note the "zu" in the first sentence. It makes the phrase a directive:

Something **is to be** based on something.

Also, we have "nach dem Marktordnungsrecht" (= "according to market regulations"), so the "something" the import price is supposed to be based on isn't even stated, only the "why" or "how".

**TL;DR:**

zu Grunde liegen = to be the basis (subject is non-human in most cases)

zu Gunde legen = to use something as a basis for something else (subject is human in most cases)